# Public variable doesn't show up in class members list

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, mahapps.metro

I am totally new to this language, so I feel it is a bit silly question ..

I am trying to create a hamburger menu with the MahApps.Metro framework through an example from [his example repository](https://github.com/punker76/code-samples/tree/MahApps/v1.6.5/MahAppsMetroHamburgerMenu/), the V4 versión with MVVM.

Copying all the structure of his example, it works correctly, but now I don't know how to continue. I don't know how to get the properties of my MainViewModel from my SearchViewModel, because when accessing the object I don't see its properties.

[image]

[image]

Also, I don't know how to bind these properties or how to link a button in the SearchView.xaml with an action that uses MainViewModel properties.

This are all my relevant classes, but you can follow the example from [his example repo](https://github.com/punker76/code-samples/tree/MahApps/v1.6.5/MahAppsMetroHamburgerMenu/)

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid.Resources>
    <core:SelectedItemToContentConverter x:Key="SelectedItemToContentConverter" />

    <!--  this is the template for the items (options too)  -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem}">
        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Height="48" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Icon}" Focusable="False" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Label}" />
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=IsPaneOpen}" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="RootGrid" Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--  these are the templates for the view models  -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:HomeViewModel}">
        <views:HomeView DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:PrivateViewModel}">
        <views:PrivateView DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SettingsViewModel}">
        <views:SettingsView DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:AboutViewModel}">
        <views:AboutView DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Controls:HamburgerMenu Grid.Row="1" x:Name="HamburgerMenuControl" HamburgerVisibility="Hidden" HamburgerWidth="48" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" IsPaneOpen="True" SelectedIndex="0" Style="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuCreatorsStyle}" OpenPaneLength="350" VerticalScrollBarOnLeftSide="False" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <!--  select the tag (ViewModel) of the selected item (options item)  -->
        <Controls:HamburgerMenu.Content>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedItemToContentConverter}">
                <Binding FallbackValue="{x:Null}" Mode="OneWay" Path="SelectedItem.Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                <Binding FallbackValue="{x:Null}" Mode="OneWay" Path="SelectedOptionsItem.Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Controls:HamburgerMenu.Content>
    </Controls:HamburgerMenu>

</Grid.Resources>
```

**PropertyChangedViewModel base model**

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using JetBrains.Annotations;

namespace ExampleProject.ViewModels
{
    public class PropertyChangedViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel**

```cs
namespace ExampleProject.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedViewModel
    {
        private HamburgerMenuItemCollection _menuItems;
        private HamburgerMenuItemCollection _menuOptionItems;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.CreateMenuItems();
        }

        public void CreateMenuItems()
        {
            MenuItems = new HamburgerMenuItemCollection
            {
                new HamburgerMenuIconItem()
                {
                    Icon = new PackIconMaterial() {Kind = PackIconMaterialKind.Magnify},
                    Label = "Search Item",
                    ToolTip = "The Search view.",
                    Tag = new SearchViewModel(this)
                },
                new HamburgerMenuIconItem()
                {
                    Icon = new PackIconMaterial() {Kind = PackIconMaterialKind.CreditCardOutline},
                    Label = "Payment item",
                    ToolTip = "Payment.",
                    Tag = new PaymentViewModel(this)
                },
                new HamburgerMenuIconItem()
                {
                    Icon = new PackIconMaterial() {Kind = PackIconMaterialKind.BookmarkMultipleOutline},
                    Label = "The Bookmarks",
                    ToolTip = "The bookmarks item.",
                    Tag = new BookmarksViewModel(this)
                }
            };

            MenuOptionItems = new HamburgerMenuItemCollection
            {
                new HamburgerMenuIconItem()
                {
                    Icon = new PackIconMaterial() {Kind = PackIconMaterialKind.Help},
                    Label = "About",
                    ToolTip = "Some help.",
                    Tag = new AboutViewModel(this)
                }
            };
        }

        public HamburgerMenuItemCollection MenuItems
        {
            get { return _menuItems; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _menuItems)) return;
                _menuItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public HamburgerMenuItemCollection MenuOptionItems
        {
            get { return _menuOptionItems; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _menuOptionItems)) return;
                _menuOptionItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SearchViewModel**

```cs
namespace ExampleProject.ViewModels
{
    public class SearchViewModel : PropertyChangedViewModel
    {
        private readonly PropertyChangedViewModel _mainViewModel;

        public SearchViewModel(PropertyChangedViewModel mainViewModel)
        {
            _mainViewModel = mainViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

**SearchView.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="ExampleProject.Views.SearchView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExampleProject.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Search View"
                   FontSize="32"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**SearchView.xaml (code behind)**

```
namespace ExampleProject.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logic of interaction for SearchtView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SearchView : UserControl
    {
        public SearchView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PropertyChangedViewModel` does not have `myGlobalVar`, `MainViewModel` has.

you have to cast `mainViewModel` to `MainViewModel` because `mainViewModel` is of type `PropertyChangedViewModel` and not `MainViewModel`.

```
((MainViewModel)mainViewModel).myGlobalVar = ...
```

This is why respecting the "naming conventions" is very important, hadn't you named it after the wrong class, you wouldn't have confused it with another class.

Also in order for the binding to work, the class member must be a public property or else it is not accessible from XAML and it won't show up in XAML intellisense.

If you don't want it to be public you must use `DependencyProperty` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I tried and now I can access the properties in each viewModel. I tried binding this property to a label, but don´t work. I tried `<Label Content="{Binding Path=_mainViewModel.myGlobalVar} />"` and `<Label Content="{Binding _mainViewModel.myGlobalVar}"` and nothing... How can I bind to the properties?

Comment: I tried too: `public string message;` and `this.message = _mainViewModel.myGlobalVar;` and binding with `<Label Content="{Binding message} />"`and neither...

Comment: @Randolf that's because you are binding a field and not a property. Moreover you must provide a way to inform the view of the changes you make to the view model or otherwise it will be a one-time binding. this is too basic and long to explain here.

Comment: @Randolf, just to give you some clue, from class members "only public properties" show up in XAML, and also DPs. And also follow the pattern of `MenuOptionItems` in that sample

Comment: I thought that when deriving from the `PropertyChangedViewModel` class I would not have to follow the same pattern as `MenuOptionItems` and call `OnPropertyChanged ();` in each set ... What is that interface for then then if I have to make the call to `OnPropertyChanged () ;` manually?

Comment: Ok, I got it.. the inheritance serves so you don't have to declare
  the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` event and the `OnPropertyChanged` function in each viewModel... Now I just have to figure out how to link the click on a button with a function in the viewModel ... Thank you!